# syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN error with "?" in variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Why does the Test.foo work, but Test2.foo? fail.

It seems it works without the '?', but I would prefer to have the ? to follow conversation that it's a boolean.

> syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN

#### Works:

```
class Test
  def foo
    @foo ||= true  # => true
  end           # => :foo

end  # => :foo
```

#### FAILS:

```
class Test2
  def foo?
    @foo? ||= true  # => true
  end           # => :foo

end  # => :foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` symbol is allowed at the end of a method name but `@foo` is an instance **variable**, not a method. And `?` is not allowed in variables names

Comment: What is the convention to show it's a boolean when using variable names?

Comment: I'd personally call it `@is_foo`, not sure about conventions

Comment: @GProst, Using `is_...` is a common way of defining it. Programming teams often have that as a standard, along with whether they're using CamelCase or snake_case, etc.